# I am trying to put back a seat to the total available seats but getting wrong values. Any ideas how to fix?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]
Please review the attached screenshot. The image above the red line shows the summary of training class a user signed up for.

Of particular interest on that image is the column header called `Available`.

Anytime a user signs up for a training, that number descreases by 1.

For instance, the current available seat is 29 according to the image. If a user signs up for this class, the number decreases by 1 to 28.

This works well so far.

In the event that the user decides, s/he can't take the class that s/he signed up for whatever reason, the user will need to click the `Cancel Training` button to remove that class from his/her list as shown in the image below the read line.

When this happens, it frees up a seat.

This works fine as well.

What we would like to do is add that seat back to the list on image above the red line.

So, assuming the `Available` seat is 28 and the user cancels his/her seat, we would like to put that seat back so now it increases by 1 to 29.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but this code below displays all the seats, rather that the record that shows 28 seats.

```
Insert into tblTrainings (availableSeats)
select (t.availableseats+1)availableseats
from   tblTrainings t Inner Join tblCourses c on t.courseId = c.courseId  
       Inner Join tblLocations l on t.locationId = l.LocationId  
       Inner Join tblTrainingDates d on c.dateid=d.dateid  
       Inner Join tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId  
       Inner Join tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId
where t.locationid=2;
DELETE FROM tblTrainings WHERE trainingId = @trainingid and username = @uchide"
```

Just a little info about the design.

We have the following lookup tables:

tblLocations, tblCourses, tblInstructors, tblCourseInstructor, tblTrainingDates

Comment: Please provide the relevant code that is called when a user "cancels" their seat and you update your db.

Comment: "this code below displays all the seats" - That SQL doesn't display anything.  It INSERTs copies of records from tblTrainings with locationid=2 into tblTrainings, with availableseats 1 greater than the original records.  Can you please take another stab at describing what you are doing and what the error is?

Comment: You shouldn't store the available number of seats at all. Store only the capacity of a course and the relationship between the course and students.

Comment: You should probably start by doing a `SELECT * FROM tblTrainings` before and after cancelling a seat, and see if the result in the database is what you expect.

Comment: @Devon, sorry I left the delete out in error. I just added it now.

mbeckish, yes you are right. What I meant was that if I ran the select alone, just to see what is being returned, it isn't returning expected results.

No errors, just not the correct results as indicated.

Jodrell, I am sure that would have saved me this additional frustration. Any examples on how to handled it in such that cancelling a class would automatically add the seat back?

Comment: @Kenny: As suggested by Jodrell, I agree the best method is to only store the max-number of seats in a course and the connections between students and the course. Then you can easily calculate the number of available seats by the max-seats minus the number of connections. So when you add/remove seats and correctly add/remove the db connection the available amount of seats always correctly adjusts automatically.

Comment: You are copying (via INSERT..SELECT) records where `where t.locationid=2;`, yet you are deleting records where `trainingId = @trainingid and username = @uchide`.  Are you sure these two sets of search criteria match the records they are supposed to?

Comment: @mbeckish, trainingid is a unique primary key on tblTrainings table. so, if you delete that uniqueId, I don't  think you can perform a join with it anymore; just as I don't think you can perform a join with username as it may no longer exist on the main table which is tblTrainings table.

Devon, I agree with you and Jodrell. That was what I had in mind when I started designing this but I had issues coming up with the code. If you guys can offer that up, that would fantastic.

Comment: @Kenny - "so, if you delete that uniqueId, I don't think you can perform a join with it anymore".  Yes, but are you sure the criteria you are using are correct?  Are you sure `where t.locationid=2;` selects the record you want to increment, and `trainingId = @trainingid and username = @uchide` selects the correct record to delete?

Comment: @mbeckis, Yes, the delete works fine. Anytime, I hit the delete button, it deletes the record I would like to see deleted.

All that is left is to recognize that each delete frees up a seat and we need to figure out a way to add that one seat back.

What Joddrel and Devon are suggesting will work best for me if we can figure it out.

Comment: @Kenny - So you're saying the INSERT..SELECT doesn't work?  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: @mbeckish, here are the issues.

First, using locationId alone inserts the seat for the wrong record for that particular location. For instance, if there are 3 records for locationId=2, those 3 records could come from 3 different courses and each course has a capacity seating of 30. So, it puts 1 into wrong course. Oh wait a minute! Since it inserts it back before deleting then I could join the username and training Id and we should be fine but why one being inserted into wrong course?

Comment: @Kenny - Sounds like you're on the right track.  Go back through your data model and make sure you *really* understand it.  Guessing at queries never works out.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do what Jodrell and @Devon suggested about not storing AvailableSeats on the db?

Right now, I am getting an error that date of training cannot be null.

We are not trying to save dates. Dates can only be saved after user registers.

Comment: @Kenny If you would like I can post a detailed explanation of this alternative data tracking system as an answer; I unfortunately cannot post the exact code because I don't know the structure of your DB but I can give a clear enough explanation that you should be able to make some small simple edits to your DB and it should work (once you get the code for the new system up and running of course).

Comment: @Devon,

First, thank you. I got the code working like I want it by changing my INSERT to UPDATE. It dawned on me that I was over-thinking the solution. Since I was interested in was increase the total count of availableSeats, I didn't do to perform an INSERT statement.

However, I would still very much appreciate the code snippet because I would rather not have store AvailableSeats on the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From chat you mentioned you would like a solution that does not require storing the AvailableSeats on your DB.

There are two general solutions to this problem. One being very easy to code with some scalability issues; and the other that is a little more convoluted but will scale fine with your website.

Steps of the first solution:

- Add a Variable Column to your User Table that stores a course ID for each user
- Create the simple UPDATE queries that add/remove the course ID for each user when they enroll/drop a course
- To automatically track available seats have two queries

  - One that collects the MaxSeats from the course table
  - And another that queries all users in the User Table and counts all users that have the selected course ID in their course ID field.

As long as one has a basic understanding of UPDATE, and SELECT queries implementing this should be pretty simple when given the correct DB structure.

NOTE: This has some scalability issues because when you get a massive amount of users you are required to search through every single one of them for their course ID; and the load time increases with the user amount.

Steps of the second solution:

- Add a variable column to your Course Table that would hold a string representing an array of user IDs
- Implement code that can break-down, process, edit, and reconstruct the array string
- Implement code that subtracts the amount of users in that array from the maxSeats value.

NOTE: Although this solution still uses simple UPDATE queries on the back-end, the process of creating the tracking systems to manage the array structure can be very tedious.

Many users would think a third solution would be similar to the first but to also add a column to the Course Table with the availableSeats and incriment/decriment by 1 whenever a user enrolls/drops a course.

This may technically work; but it is inefficient because you are unnecessarily using extra space on your DB back-end. This is unnecessary because you need the course IDs attached to each user to know who is in the course; and with that alone you can figure out how many seats are left `(AvailableSeats = MaxSeats - NumPeopleEnrolled)`.

Comment: Ok, in the interest of time - I have gone really deep with this and user testing is tomorrow, I will stick with what I have.

Going forward, I will attempt one your recommended solutions.

Thanks for the time and assistance.

Comment: @Kenny That is understandable, and no problem that is what SO is for.